# Variable population delay when using Observable subscription

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, observable

I’m passing some data, which is an array of objects, from one component to a page. For this I was using a service with a Subject and an Observable, like this:

**myservice.service.ts**

```js
private mySubject = new Subject<{ data1:string, data2:number, data3: Object }[]>();
public myObservable = this.mySubject.asObservable();

changeDataFunction(data: { data1:string, data2:number, data3: Object }[]) {
    this.mySubject.next(data);
}
```

I was sending the data from the component to my page this way, which is the way I pass data from components and between pages from some time:

**mycomponent.component.ts**

```js
this.myService.changeDataFunction(myData);
```

And receiving the data in my page this way:

**mypage.page.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.mySubscription = this.myService.myObservable.subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); // I can see the data in console
        console.log(data.length); // Returns 0
    
        // process data
        ...
    });
}

...

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Well, my problem is that when I try to process the data, it is empty. If I check the data on the console, I can see that it is there, even though it appears with the empty array symbol (`[]`), but I can open it and see the info. Just below, the size of this array is returned as 0, which suggests that the variable has not yet been populated at the time I am trying to process it, but is already populated by the time I check the console.

I would like to know a way to carry out the processing only when this variable is actually populated. I imagined that when I got the subscription trigger this variable should already be populated, regardless of its size. This is the first time that something like this happens with this methodology, I imagine it is due to the size of the array (30 objects +).

---

I was suggested to change the declaration of the Observable in the service, removing the `asObservable ()` method. For this I did the following:

**myservice.service.ts**

```js
class Service {
    private mySubject = new Subject<MultiGeometryFeature[]>();

    changeDataFunction(data: MultiGeometryFeature[]) {
        this.mySubject.next(data);
    }
    
    myObservable(): Observable<MultiGeometryFeature[]> {
        return this.mySubject;
    }
}

export interface MultiGeometryFeature {
    data1: string;
    data2: number;
    data3: Object;
}
```

Unfortunately the main problem keeps happening.

*Some infos*

```
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
@angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
rxjs                          : 6.5.3
```

You can see more details about this problem on the [parallel thread in the Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/help-to-understanding-variable-population-through-an-observable-and-subscription/191691?u=leonardofmed).

Comment: When you use `changeDataFunction(data)` to emit data , is the data an empty array ? because `Subject` just broadcast whatever you provide in `next(...)`, if `next()` is called and nothing is provided , it broadcast a `null`, not an empty array.

Comment: I logged the `data` and `data.length` in the component before sending to the service, inside the function in the service and in the subscription of the page. In all logs I see the same thing, the `data.length with length = 0` but the correct populated array in the `data` log. From what you said I think I can conclude that the problem is related to the asynchronicity of the formation of the original variable `data` in the component that is sent to the service. I'll try to fix this, perhaps encapsulating the formation of this array in a `Promise`.

Comment: Yeah, the formation of the original data was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it help, happy coding !